# SocketError: Connection refused using py2neo to a remote server

Tags: authentication, py2neo

While this issue has been addressed a couple of times in the past at SO and I tried all the suggestions, the problem still remains and I am hoping someone would shine a light on this.

My company set up a neo4j (v2.1.6) graph database at a remote ubuntu server. 
In order to modify and update data into the server, I am using a python package, py2neo.

The server's endpoint address is http://fake-address.com/db/data and the authentication Id/password are 'fakeId' and 'fakePassWord'.

In order to access the remote database, in my local machine python terminal,

I tried the following:

```
from py2neo import authenticate, Graph
authenticate("fake-address.com:80", "fakeId", "fakePassWord")
graph = Graph("http://fake-address.com:80/db/data/")
result = graph.cypher.execute("CREATE (a:Color)")
```

Unfortunately, the above command resulted in the following error message.

```
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/core.pyc in execute(self, statement, parameters, **kwparameters)
107         """
108         if self.transaction_uri:
--> 109             tx = CypherTransaction(self.transaction_uri)
110             tx.append(statement, parameters, **kwparameters)
111             results = tx.commit()

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/core.pyc in __init__(self, uri)
180         self.__commit = None
181         self.__finished = False
--> 182         self.graph = self.__begin.graph
183 
184     def __enter__(self):

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/core.pyc in graph(self)
211         :rtype: :class:`.Graph`
212         """
--> 213         return self.__service_root.graph
214 
215     @property

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/core.pyc in graph(self)
523         if self.__graph is None:
524             try:
--> 525                 uri = self.resource.metadata["data"]
526             except KeyError:
527                 if "authentication" in self.resource.metadata:

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/core.pyc in metadata(self)
226             if self.__initial_metadata is not None:
227                 return self.__initial_metadata
--> 228             self.get()
229         return self.__last_get_response.content
230 

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/core.pyc in get(self, headers, redirect_limit, **kwargs)
271         kwargs.update(cache=True)
272         try:
   --> 273             response = self.__base.get(headers=headers, redirect_limit=redirect_limit, **kwargs)
274         except (ClientError, ServerError) as error:
275             if error.status_code == UNAUTHORIZED:

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.pyc in get(self, if_modified_since, headers, redirect_limit, **kwargs)
964             object from which content can be read
965         """
--> 966         return self.__get_or_head("GET", if_modified_since, headers, redirect_limit, **kwargs)
967 
968     def put(self, body=None, headers=None, **kwargs):

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.pyc in __get_or_head(self, method, if_modified_since, headers, redirect_limit, **kwargs)
941             headers["If-Modified-Since"] = formatdate(datetime_to_timestamp(if_modified_since), usegmt=True)
942         rq = Request(method, self.uri, None, headers)
--> 943         return rq.submit(redirect_limit=redirect_limit, **kwargs)
944 
945     def head(self, if_modified_since=None, headers=None, redirect_limit=5, **kwargs):

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.pyc in submit(self, redirect_limit, **response_kwargs)
431         uri = self.uri
432         while True:
--> 433             http, rs = submit(self.method, uri, self.body, self.headers)
434             status_class = rs.status // 100
435             if status_class == 3:

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.pyc in submit(method, uri, body, headers)
360                                       host_port=uri.host_port)
361         else:
--> 362             raise SocketError(code, description, host_port=uri.host_port)
363     else:
364         return http, response

SocketError: Connection refused
```

Sorry about the long error message and I greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: are you positive the server is running on port 80?  default port is 7474.

it appears that python can't make a tcp connection at all.

are you able to access http://fake-address.com:80/db/data/ through your web browser (without any proxies configured)?

you can see the port configured in conf/neo4j-server.properties.  property line looks like: org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474 for the default port.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed with my company and the server is running on port 80. Just to be safe, I tried with 7474 and it didn't work either. Also, I am able to access fake-address.com:80/db/data/ in my web browser just fine. This is very confusing to me.

Comment: do you get connected when you type the following in your terminal 'telnet fake-address.com 80' ?  and is the IP address printed out what you'd expect it to be?  wondering if there's a proxy server set up in your browser.

Comment: OP - as Ryan suggests, this is a networking problem unrelated to neo4j.  Also check any firewall configuration that your host might have blocking traffic.  The telnet check is a good idea too.

Comment: please also try using 'watch', which will print out the debug messages from  httpstream.  add to your imports  "from py2neo import watch".  then call 'watch("httpstream")' before you make any requests.  you should see which specific IP and port py2neo is connecting to.

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful suggestions. I edited "tags" to fit more appropriate to the issue above. Regarding the telnet suggestion, when I tried it, it did show an IP address and said it was connected to the host name. So, it seems like the problem is in the "incoming" to my local machine.  However, my firewall setting is configured to "off", allowing any incoming connections. I know I initially asked about neo4j, but if you have an idea what the problem might be, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: once you connect via telnet, you can try "GET /db/data HTTP/1.0" and press enter twice and see if it returns a response. also, did you get a chance to try the 'watch' option i mentioned above?  that'll give a log of what IPs it's actually trying to connect to.  it may be that the initial connection works, but there's a followup connection happening.

Comment: With Telnet, after "Trying IP.ADDRESS...Connected to fake-address.com. Escape character is '^]'.", I typed "GET /db/data HTTP/1.0". Unfortunately, the connection was lost with "HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized Cache-Control:no-cache Connection: close Content-Type: text/html WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Neo4j"
<html><body><h1>401 Unauthorized</h1>
You need a valid user and password to access this content. ". Do I need to give my ID and Password with the port address?

Comment: Also, I tried "watch" option, I received the followings before it crashed:  "> GET http://fake-address.com:80/db/data/ < 200 OK [842] > GET http:/// ! SocketError: Connection refused". Do you still think it's a firewall issue? Is the firewall setting in my system preference independent of the firewall setting in my terminal?

Comment: Ok, after telnet and Curl test, I came to the conclusion that the problem lies  NOT in the connection but in the authentication in py2neo. With Curl, I was able to create a note remotely from my local machine but failed in py2neo. So, my guess is that the authentication from py2neo is not correctly sending the user and password information. Any idea why it is that? Is there any a syntax issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. The problem must have been in the authentication in py2neo. With the newest version of py2neo (2.0.4), the connection was properly made.