# Connecting docker instance with python notebook to docker instance with Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, docker, jupyter-notebook, py2neo

I am running a Jupyter notebook docker instance (https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/all-spark-notebook) and I've installed py2neo on it.

I am also running a docker container with Neo4J installed with port 7474 exposed.

The problem is I cannot seem to connect to the REST interface of the Neo4J docker from the notebook docker. I think the problem is related to the definition of localhost.

What worked so far. I used only the Neo4J docker and start a local notebook (ipython notebook) then the following works:

```
import py2neo

from py2neo import Node, Relationship, Graph, authenticate

authenticate("http://localhost:7474", "neo4j", "admin")

graph = Graph('http://localhost:7474/db/data') 

graph.cypher.execute('match (y:Year) return y')
```

The same code doesn't work in the notebook which is running in a separate docker container since the definition of localhost is not the same. But now I don't understand what it should be:

I've used **docker inspect** on the Neo4J container and used the following two in an attempt to find the address corresponding to my localhost:

- "Gateway": "xxx.yy.42.1"
- "IPAddress": "xxx.yy.0.3"

But both of them result in `ClientError: 401 Unauthorized`

Any suggestion on how to overcome this issue?
(Note that my current docker version is 1.7.1, thus not support network yet, but I could obviously upgrade if that's necessary.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224779/socketerror-connection-refused-using-py2neo-to-a-remote-server seems to be related. One of the answers suggests that there might be a problem with the authenticate function. We've taken a look with Wireshark and the request sent from the docker instance contains no authentication info while from the local python notebook it correctly has.

Comment: You could try disabling Neo4j authentication to confirm if this is the problem. Set `dbms.security.auth_enabled=false` in conf/neo4j-server.properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
graph = Graph('https://' + username + ':' + pwd + '@' + ip_neo + ':7473 /db/data')
```

This seems to work. Note that you need port 7473 which is the standard HTTPS port. No success getting the approach with authenticate to work.

For ip_neo I inspect the neo4J docker instance:

```
sudo docker inspect neo4j | grep "Gateway"
```